# Count unique values that appear more than X times

Tags: r, unique, distinct-values

I have a large dataset (9 mlm obs.) with customer unique id numbers appearing multiple times. I want to know how many customers appear more than 100 times (or more than any X times).

I know to count unique values you do this:

```
# Count unique values in column “customer_no”
length(unique(data.frame$customer_no))
```

But how can I add the extra condition that says *"if they appear more than X times in data.frame"*?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
n <- 100
library(data.table)
sum(setDT(df)[,.N>n, by=id]$V1)
#[1] 13632
```

Or

```
 sum(table(df$id)>n)
 #[1] 13632
```

#### data

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(id=sample(paste0(letters,1:1e5),9e6,replace=TRUE), val=rnorm(9e6))
```